# Is the Filipino word "buwisit" really from Hokkien?

Tags: etymology

I've read a couple of times the word being attributed to Hokkien. This wiktionary [entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buwisit) claims the same. I'm not convinced though.

Answer (score 4):

《闽南方言大词典》has the following entry on page 127:

[image: hai]

> [无围翼] <漳> bo2-6 ui2-6 sit8 倒霉：盖～，佫拄着停电(真倒霉，又碰上停电) | ～甲伊做翁仔姐仔(跟他做夫妻很倒霉)。

So, this is attributed as 漳泉話 -or- Quanzhang Minnan, which is Hokkien - *bo ui sit* does sound quite similar to *buwisit* and the meaning (倒霉) does fit as well.

---

無衣食 does seem to be the more appropriate spelling of *bo ui sit*.

[image: test]

衣食 means:

> 好運天賜食穿無缺。

Comment: This is an awesome answer; do you just happen to have this dictionary lying around?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete I found a pdf copy of《闽南方言大词典》through a quick baidu search, just to answer this question. I'm not sure what the source of the second picture is, though.